# Copy column data based on a specific year

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have an Excel sheet with prices (of materials used in construction) from previous years.

I am trying to make a code that will show me all the data based on a certain year that I choose.

What my list/excel looks like
[image]

In cell E3 (in yellow), I input the year to "analyse".
I need a function that will search columns K to Q (and more since every year, prices change), for that year, and copy all the data of sales, reg. loc. and spec. loc. into the columns F, G and H.

If it's easier that, instead of putting the year in cells K3, L3 and M3 (for example), if I put it in cell N3, R3, etc. (in red) instead, the function will take the 3 previous columns and copy/paste them in columns F to H.

Option 2, if it makes the coding easier
[image]

Also the list goes until row 381, and there's a potential that more data will be input eventually so take into consideration as if the list had an infinite amount of rows. However, for the columns, it's always fixed to 3 columns.

FYI: it is not a school project. I'm trying to simplify my work instead of manually searching and copy/pasting the data every time.

Comment: "making the code easier" is something strange, since you did not show anything  to prove you have a code project in your mind. Then, what kind of research did you on internet and how does the approach to be followed look, since you know how is easier? In principle, it is the same to place the year in both ways (only to be consistent in doing that), then use `Find` on the third row to find the first column containing the searched string. Since the necessary data is located in that column, plus the following two, it should be easy to extract the necessary data and copy it in the necessary place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It should do what (I understand) you need. It should be fast, not using clipboard for copying. As I suggested in my comment, it firstly searches/finds in the third row the year (long or string, as it is written in "E3"), starting searching **after "E3"**, then copying the range built according to the found cell. If not a match is found, the code exits on the line  `If rngFirstCol Is Nothing Then Exit Sub`. You may place a message there, to warn in such a case. It works on **your first arrangement/picture**, meaning that the year must be filled in the third row of the first column where from the necessary data should be collected/copied:

```
Sub ExtractPricesPerYear()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngFirstCol As Range, lngYear, necCol As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your necessary sheet
   lngYear = sh.Range("E3").value 'the year to be searched
  Set rngFirstCol = sh.rows(3).Find(What:=lngYear, After:=sh.Range("E3"), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
  If rngFirstCol Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  necCol = rngFirstCol.Column
  lastR = sh.cells(sh.rows.count, necCol).End(xlUp).row
  With sh.Range(rngFirstCol.Offset(1), sh.cells(lastR, necCol + 2))
        sh.Range("E4").Resize(.rows.count, .Columns.count).value = .value
  End With
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

And another issue: It is good to show us what you tried by your own. If not a piece of code, at least, something to prove that you investigated and had some ideas about the task to be solved, asking for hints, suggestions etc. proving that you know something about **how** it can be done...

**Edited**:

Following your requirement from last comment, please use the next solution. Please, copy the next code in the respective sheet code module (right click on the sheet name, then choose `View Code`):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     Dim lastR As Long, lastRF As Long, rngFirstCol As Range, lngYear, necCol As Long
  
    If Target.Address(0, 0) = "E3" Then 'the code exits for any other change on the sheet
         lngYear = Target.value 'the year to be searched
        Set rngFirstCol = Me.rows(3).Find(What:=lngYear, After:=Me.Range("E3"), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
        If rngFirstCol Is Nothing Then MsgBox "No such year found on the third row...:":   Exit Sub
        
        necCol = rngFirstCol.Column 'column number of the found cell
        lastR = Me.cells(Me.rows.count, necCol).End(xlUp).row   'last row on the found column
        lastRF = Me.Range("F" & Me.rows.count).End(xlUp).row  'last row on F:F column (to delete its content, if any)
           If lastRF > 4 Then Me.Range("F4:H" & lastRF).ClearContents 'clear the range to make place for the new data
        With Me.Range(rngFirstCol.Offset(1), Me.cells(lastR, necCol + 2))
              Me.Range("F4").Resize(.rows.count, .Columns.count).value = .value
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This code is working!! The only problem is that it starts to paste the data in column E to G instead of F to H. Also, is there a way to make it automatic as in everytime i change the year in cell E3, AUTOMATICALLY excel will run the macro without me going on the macro tab and clicking on run macro? P.S: I didn't try VBA, i tried using VLOOKUP and MATCHLIST. I have no knowledge when it comes to VBA which is why I came here and researching about it!!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But now I am driving... I will adapt the code (in an event) to work as you need.

Comment: @Batata Even trying something different than VBA, you should show us what you tried (that **you tried something**). We usually help people trying to help themselves, not the one just asking for solutions... Please, try the event code I pasted after **Edited**. You should copy it in the necessary code module... I would like to receive some feedback after testing it.

Comment: I just figured out how to make the macro automatically run. I created a private sub and used the function Call (that redirects the code and runs the macro as soon as the cell E3 changes). I'll try to fit your code with the one you previously made, excluding the code for the cell change (of course). Here is what i made:

Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$E$3" Then
    Call ExtractPricesPerYear
    
End If
End Sub

Comment: @Batata Even Did you try my last code? How "Call (that redirects the code and runs the macro as soon as the cell E3 changes)" without using the sheet `Change` event?

Comment: However, since you wanted to know, I tried your code (without my Call code) and it works perfectly just as I needed :) Thank you very much, it is super appreciated!!

Comment: @Batata Even Glad I could help! But I would also like to tell you that we here, when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the proposed solution works as it should...